# Update statement in linq with external SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-update

I have a problem with update of a table via linq.

I execute the following code for it

```
    tbl_Customer tblcust= new tbl_Customer();
    tbl_Customer tcust = obj.tbl_Customers.Single(c => c.C_ID == 1);
    tblcust.C_Name = txtcname.Text;
    tblcust.C_Address = txtcaddress.Text;
    tblcust.C_Mobile =Convert.ToInt64( txtcmobile.Text);
    obj.SubmitChanges();
```

But this code does not affect the records in table. I use an external SQL Server to connect with database, help me to resolve this stuff.

Comment: i think you should assign values to tcust and not tblcust which is an new object

Answer (score 2):

Why would it? `tblcust` is nothing to do with the ORM, and the data-context (`obj`) *has never heard of* the object referenced by `tblcust`. You meant to update `tcust` instead:

```
tcust.C_Name = txtcname.Text;
tcust.C_Address = txtcaddress.Text;
tcust.C_Mobile =Convert.ToInt64( txtcmobile.Text);
```

`tcust` came from the ORM, and is known to the data-context's change manager, thus it will spot the changes to `tcust` and apply them to the database.